# Adding to Sharepoint list brings up a distorted page

Tags: list

Has anyone encountered an issue where you try to add an item to a list in Sharepoint and then the add page shows up as distorted? I want to post the image but I cannot as I am a newbie.

The page is all grayed out - there is no option to input anything.

I thought this could be caused by a toolbar but it's not. We disabled that but it did not fix the issue. Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Karen

Comment: Use F12 developer tools to check out the CSS of the different objects on the page. If there is custom branding of your site you may have to mess around with your masters. Good to note however is you can add the class "s4-notdlg" to any objects to get them to not appear in modal windows.

Comment: Or perhaps verify that your NewForm.aspx page is intact.

Answer (score 1):

So we found out that there is this application that causes this. If this application (SilkTest) is running and then the agent starts up, the user will see that distorted page when updating the list.

You can only update the list if you close out the agent completely.